# How to open an HTML file in QtextBrowser

Tags: c++, qt

I have a ready-made HTML file, if it is opened through a browser, then a normal `web page` is displayed.

How can this `HTML file` be opened via the `QTextBrowser` widget so that structured information is also displayed in it as a `web page`?

I've tried something like this:

```
QFile file("/home/alex/data.html");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    QMessageBox::information(nullptr,"info",file.errorString());
QTextStream in(&file);
ui->textBrowser->setHtml(in.readAll());
```

but it didn't work out.

Comment: According to the docs, "This class extends QTextEdit (in read-only mode), adding some navigation functionality so that users can follow links in hypertext documents." Reading between the lines, I'd venture that the hyperlink navigation is the only (or primary) extension. In other words, it's not going to act like a full-featured browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are dedicated classes to display full webpages:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html

In your case, QTextBrowser can "only" display rich text following HTML tags.